# Weird spacing in Hex to String

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a hex to string converter and for some reason the spacing between bytes in the conversion is multiplied by 2.

I would like it to spit out a single space between characters,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "");
        string StrValue = "";
        while (textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            StrValue += System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Substring(2, textBox2.Text.Length - 2);             
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + StrValue + " ";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Conversion Error Occurred : " + ex.Message, "Conversion Error");
    }
}
```

so "41 41" converted would look like "A A", but this is what happens:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVyMo.png)
Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code instead of showing the code in image!

Comment: first of all do do calculations/manipulations in the text boxes. decouple using some vars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + StrValue + " ";
```

you consequently append the result of calculations to your `TextBox1`.

So, after the first iteration the result is `A`, you append it and a whitespace to `TextBox1`.
Then, you take the second `41` and convert it. Now, `StrValue` is `AA` and you append it and space to `TextBox1`, and so on.

You need to move this line out of your `while` loop:

```
textBox1.Clear();
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "");

string StrValue = "";

while (textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{

    StrValue += System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Substring(2, textBox2.Text.Length - 2);             
}

textBox1.Text = StrValue;
```

As some people mentioned in comments, you need to stop working with `TextBox`es this way. It is pretty confusing. You may want to do the following:

```
private string HexToString(string hex)
{
    string result = "";

    while (hex.Length > 0) 
    {
        result += Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16));
        hex = hex.Substring(2); // no need to specify the end
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, in your button click event or wherever else:

```
textBox1.Text = HexToString(textBox2.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
```

As simple as that. Or you can even move replacing the whitespaces in the method. Now, this code is readable and is logically separated.

Comment: @user3809661 You may want to accept the answer, if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the accumulated value in `StrValue`. You should define that variable inside your while, and assign it only (don't append a new value).

```
while (textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    string StrValue = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Substring(2, textBox2.Text.Length - 2);             
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + StrValue + " ";
}
```